# How to run VBA code from external file?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with VBA scripts in its background.

I also have an external file generated in a separate process that contains VBA functions i need to integrate into the main Excel.

Today, I copy-n-paste the external functions into the excel editor manually.

I wonder if there is a way to `include` or `import` the external functions without me copy-n-paste them.

Comment: Check here:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: You can use `Application.Run` for that purpose. The workbook containing the code must be open. Consider loading it as an Add-in.

Comment: there is a way looking into the vbproject, plus export\import, can't show you now, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Same problem here, did you eventually found a suitable solution? In that case, you should post it as an (accepted) answer.

Answer (score 0):

*2017-06-18 was 5 years, 1 month and 16 days ago...

But I sincerely believe that this Q should have a simpler answer than what was provided in the comments (ref: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx).*

---

To be able to call functions that are resident in another Excel Workbook than the currently active one;

1. The other_Workbook has to be open in Excel
2. e.g. if using a function in a cell, specify the name (of the other workbook) as in `=other_Workbook!FunctionName(arguments)`
3. a similar (workbook name prepended) approach may work for e.g. Sub:s.

Note that your/the VBA-code will run at least once for each reference (call) you have made to the function.

This may become sluggish in case of careless use.